# Wrong encoding in Joomla 3

Tags: encoding, joomla

I am using joomla 3 which changes character ' into â€.
Secondly it also converting any space into Â.

I tried using 
and

on myhead file but still the problem persist.

My database is with collation of utf8 too.
I am using no editor on my joomla administrator.

Also on my windows operating system it is working fine but when i push files to linux server, it shows these weird sign.
I tried google search alot but in vain.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i tried utf tag on my head section but still the problem exist.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the files you are pushing to the Linux server have encoding other than UTF-8, they might be Windows-1252.

Here's one suggestion to test if this might be the case.

Create a new text document in Notepad, then Save As, and under Encoding select UTF-8

Upload this test file and check the results.  If this still doesn't help, you might want to double check preferences on your SFTP application, just in case it is overriding file encoding.

Good luck!

Comment: thankyou david. i am gonna try that and will let you khnow.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I deactivate Google ModPagespeed on my Cpanel and my problem has been solved.

Remove "ModPagespeed On" from .htaccess